# how to generate xls file in zip file and send it to email to download there - groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

please help, I want to make an export data in the form of an xls file and it will be sent to an email so that it can be downloaded.
I use **grails, groovy**

Comment: I think you could use the Grails Mail and Grails Export (https://gpc.github.io/export/docs/index.html) plugin to achieve something like this. 

As mentioned by other people that the question seems to be too generic so you may want to join the Grails Slack (https://grails.slack.com) community for these types of queries.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a tad too generic for the stackoverflow format. I.e. you are essentially asking the community to solve the whole problem for you without prior work by you.

With that said, for email I would use something like:

http://www.simplejavamail.org/

and for generating the xls file I would use apache poi.

I.e. these are libraries you would need to add as dependencies to your project and they would help you with your task.

Comment: Grails mail plugin can be a good option too, depending on details (which were not provided).